# How to symchk against symbols stored in azure artifacts?

Tags: debugging, azure-devops, visual-studio-debugging

I have an azure build that published symbols to our organization's azure-devops symbol server. I would like to run symchk to validate that we haven't missed uploading any symbols that are needed to debug the binaries in the installers we ship to customers.

In the past we've used symchk.exe to do this. It accepts args for the binary to be checked and for the path to a symbol server or to a folder containing symbols.

But, I don't know how to get symchk.exe to validate against symbols stored as azure-devops artifacts.

I've found [help for WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/artifacts/symbols/debug-with-symbols-windbg?view=azure-devops) that explains for WinDbg you need to ensure TF.exe is in the path and also that you'll be prompted to enter a PAT token for azure-devops when prompted.

Does symchk.exe support a similar way of accessing symbols in azure? And is it possible to use it without an interactive prompt for a PAT token, as I'd like to check symbols as part of our non-interactive build script?

Comment: Why can't you run it before you publish the symbols?

Answer (score 2):

According [to this reply on the developer forums](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/598454/view.html) you can avoid a prompt for kd.exe using a sympath like

`https://[user]:[PAT]@[URL]`

So what if you set the SymbolPath arg in SymChk

```
srv*%SystemRoot%\symbols*https://basic:{PAT}@artifacts.dev.azure.com/{YOUR_ORG}/_apis/Symbol/symsrv
```

I am not 100% sure what the [user] should be, or if it will matter.

Comment: Thanks! Also, `[user]` doesn't matter.